# A c# Generics question involving Controllers and Repositories

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, generics, repository

I have a  base repository class which contains all the common repository methods (as generic):

```
public abstract class BaseRepository<T, IdType> : IBaseRepository<T, IdType>
```

My repositories from this base e.g.:

```
public class UserRepository : BaseRepository<User, int>, IUserRepository
```

I also have a base controller class containing common actions, and inherit from this in controllers.  The repository is injected into this by DI.  E.g.

```
public class UserController : BaseController<User>
{
        private readonly IUserRepository userRepository;

        public UserController (IUserRepository userRepository)
        {
            this.userRepository= userRepository;
        }
```

My question is this:  **The base controller needs to be able to access the repository methods that are defined in the base repository.  However I'm passing in via DI a different repository type for each controller (even though they all inherrit from the base repository).  How can the base controller somehow access the repository that is passed in (regardless of what type it is), so that it can access the common base methods?**

Comment: Is the `I` on the ctor meant to be on the field?

Comment: @marc Yes, sorry - typo (ok in real code) - I'll update the post.

Answer (score 1):

You can hold a reference for `BaseReposiroty` in `BaseController`

```
public class BaseController <T, IdType>
{
    ...
    ...
    protected BaseRepository<T, IdType> Reposirory
    {
        { get; set; }
    }
    ...
    ...
}
```

Comment: Hi Itay, that's what I'm trying to do - but how do I get this reference when I'm passing in a subclassed repository?

Comment: I do not understand your question

Answer (score 1):

It all your repositories will be derived from `IBaseRepository<T,IdType>`, then have:

```
interface IUserRepository : IBaseRepository<User,int> {...}
```

Now any reference to a `IUserRepository` will know about the `IBaseRepository<>` members, without having to mention concrete types like the `UserRepository` class or `BaseRepository<>` class.

Comment: Hi Marc, yes, I didn't show it in my post, but I'm already inherriting IUserRepository from IBaseRepository<User,int>.

Comment: @UpTheCreek - if you mean that you need methods from `BaseRepository<>` (the class), then you've broken the point of abstracting to the interface... if you mean the `IBaseRepository<>` interface, it should already work.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way to do it..

```
public abstract class BaseController<TEntity, TRepository, TIdType>
    where TEntity : class, new()
    where TRepository : IBaseRepository<TEntity, TIdType>
{
    protected TRepository Repository = RepositiryFactory.GetRepository<TEntity, TRepository>();

    public IList<TEntity> GetAll()
    {
        return Repository.GetAll().ToList();
    }
    public IList<TEntity> GetAll(string sortExpression)
    {
        return Repository.GetAll(sortExpression).ToList();
    }
    public int GetCount()
    {
        return Repository.GetAll().Count();
    }
    public IList<TEntity> GetAll(int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
    {
        var results = Repository.GetAll().Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
        return results.ToList();
    }
    public IList<TEntity> GetAll(string sortExpression, int startRowIndex, int maximumRows)
    {
        var results = Repository.GetAll(sortExpression).Skip(startRowIndex).Take(maximumRows);
        return results.ToList();
    }
}
```